# Windows 10 can't delete files “Invalid MS-DOS function”

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to clear files on my Windows 10 machine which I upgraded when W10 went live and I didn't have any problems at the time.

I've tried entering "sfc /scannow" in the command prompt but it didn't help

When I go to delete files I get a "Invalid MS-DOS function" error.

[image: ]]

Comment: What is the file path? If it is really long, try renaming each folder and file until it can be deleted.

Comment: run chkdsk /f to detect/repair file system issues

Comment: How did you do it? Could you delete it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ran `chkdsk /f` and later `chkdsk /r`. I hope this works.

Answer (score -1):

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/invalid-ms-dos-function-in-windows-8/3db69a2f-02dc-4adb-a0a8-2dcfb61499e5

Apparently when this happens you must boot into safe mode to delete it.

Comment: Please quote the relevant information from the link.

Answer (score -1):

I succeeded in removing such files by running Ubuntu shell (WSL) in problem directory and executing "rm ...". Supposedly, executing via Cygwin or MSYS would also succeed.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, I just selected the file on File Explorer and instead of just clicking on the big red delete button, I pressed the small arrow underneath and clicked Permanently Delete. Hope this helps!